# Table migration fails because second table references the first

Tags: node.js, postgresql, async-await, knex.js

I have two tables being created in separate migration files: `CreateReservations` and `CreateTables`. The second table references the `reservation_id` column in 'reservations' and should create a relationship between the 'reservations' table and the 'tables' table. This process is failing, but I can't pin down why, or how to fix it.

When I run `migrate:latest`, the process fails because the reservation_id column hasn't been created yet for some reason. Here's the error returned back from PostgreSQL:

> `alter table "tables" add constraint "tables_reservation_id_foreign" foreign key ("reservation_id") references "reservations" ("reservation_id") on delete CASCADE - column "reservation_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist`

Please note: the migrations work just fine if I manually run one after the other. In other words, I have a suspicion that "Tables" is running before "Reservations" for some reason.

Here are the files in my Migrations folder:

> 2021081023-**2932**_create**Reservations**Table.js

```
...createTable("reservations", (table) => {

        table.increments("reservation_id").primary();
        table.timestamps(true, true);
        table.string("first_name").notNullable();
        table.string("last_name").notNullable();
        table.string("mobile_number").notNullable();
        table.date("reservation_date").notNullable();
        table.time("reservation_time").notNullable();
        table.integer("people").notNullable();

});
```

> 2021081023-**5601**_create**Tables**Table.js

```
...createTable("tables", (table) => {

    table.increments("table_id").primary();
    table.string("table_name").notNullable();
    table.integer("capacity").notNullable();
    table
        .foreign("reservation_id")
        .references("reservation_id")
        .inTable("reservations")
        .onDelete("CASCADE");
});
```

Is there a way for me to construct a Promise that prevents any process from running out of order? An obvious fix?

(For context, this is a final assignment for a bootcamp program. The assignment is to create a website for a restaurant.)

Comment: I was hoping that adding async/await would resolve the issue, but it didn't. Same error.

`exports.up = async function(knex) {await knex.schema...`

Comment: Migrations are ran in  alphabetical order so the problem is somewhere that you are not showing in your code. Try to reduce your code to a test case that has as few code as possible and add the whole reproduction code here so that people can spot what is the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the actual column definition in your second table. You need to define the column before defining the foreign key for it.

So for example

```js
table.integer("reservation_id").unsigned();
table.foreign("reservation_id")
        .references("reservation_id")
        .inTable("reservations")
        .onDelete("CASCADE");
```